# Formal grammar with variables for consistent substitutions

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

In a rewriting system, suppose the production rule `S→xAyAz` (or `<S>:=x<A>y<A>z`, in BNF), where **S** and **A** are nonterminal symbols and **x, y, z** are any string.

This rule produces the string *xa<sub>1</sub>ya<sub>2</sub>z*, where **a<sub>1</sub>** and **a<sub>2</sub>** are strings substituted by the nonterminal symbol **A**. The substitutions **a<sub>1</sub>** and **a<sub>2</sub>** may be equal or different strings.

But what if I want to **a<sub>1</sub>** and **a<sub>2</sub>** to be the same string; that is, if the nonterminal **A** be substituted by the same instance in both its occurrences in that production rule?

I used a kind of BNF I created informally for such purpose, with `<v:A>` instead of `<A>`: a kind of "typed variable", whose type is a nonterminal symbol and the variable is the same substitution for all its occurrences. Thus, `<S>:=x<v:A>y<v:A>z`, and `<v:A>` is substituted for the same string in its both occurrences.

What is the name of such a grammar that uses variables for consistent substitution of a nonterminal? And there is a grammar formalism for it?

Comment: Your extended kind of grammar can generate the language $\{ ww : w \in \{a,b\}^* \}$, which isn’t context-free.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76186/what-would-you-get-if-you-add-parameters-to-context-free-grammars/

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yeah, I searched about it and I discovered that it is context-sensitive, but the formalisms for context-sensitive grammar that I found do not use variables as I did. I edited the question for asking for the name and formalism of such a variable-based context-sensitive grammar.

Comment: @rici I think they are different question. Mine asks for naming a nonterminal occurrence (as in `S ::= x:A x:A`, for the language `{ww:w∈{a,b}*}` ), this one you commented asks for parameterizing  a nonterminal occurrence (as in `NounPhrase(number) ::= Adjective(number) Noun(number)` for a grammar with agreement).

Comment: Well, as far as I understand that question...

Answer (score 2):

You've created an [affix grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix_grammar), so named because they were created to deal with affixes (prefixes and suffixes) in natural languages.

Specifically, this is a type of affix grammar where the "affixes" (what you call typed variables) are defined by the same type of grammar rather than coming from a simpler (finite) grammar. This creates a [two-level grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-level_grammar), specifically a type known as a [Van Wijngaarden grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Wijngaarden_grammar) after its creator.

It turns out that this type of grammar is in fact Turing-complete, so non-trivial semantic properties of such grammars are undecidable by Rice's theorem. On the one hand this makes them extremely powerful; on the other hand, it makes them not as useful in practice, since you could use some other Turing-complete system instead.